# How do you simply a complex number from exponential form

Tags: complex-numbers

$$z =\frac{ie^{i\pi/6}}{e^{\pi/4}}$$
How would I simplify this complex equation to be able to get the magnitude and angle from it? Im stumped. Ive been trying to separate it to get it in the form $z=a+bi$. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What is $j$?...

Comment: Use Euler formula.

Comment: @paw88789 you probably know it as $\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: Is that $e^{\pi / 4}$ in the denominator, and is $i$ from $z=a+bi$ the same with $j$?

Comment: Yes, j=i. Electrical engineers use j because our i is current.

Comment: @JeremyRowler Regardless, you shouldn't use *both* $i$ and $j$ for the same thing in the same question.

Comment: @dxiv Sorry, Fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $z =\cfrac{i}{e^{\pi/4}} \cdot \big(\cos(\pi / 6) + i \sin(\pi / 6)\big) =\cfrac{i}{e^{\pi/4}} \cdot \cfrac{\sqrt{3} + i}{2} = \cdots$

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense. You used Euler for the numerator!

Comment: @JeremyRowler Still doesn't tell you angle and magnitude (directly) though.

Comment: @SimpleArt That's correct, but the question was stated in terms of "*get it in the form z=a+bi*".

Comment: Hm, my bad.  Too much confusion in the question. :D

Comment: @SimpleArt Right. Your hint using polar form would have worked wonders if the denominator were $e^{i \pi / 4}\,$, instead, which is how I (mis)read it at first.

Comment: XD lol, I agree, exponents tend to be hard to read...

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. $j=e^{(4k+1)j\pi/2}$
2. $e^ae^b=e^{a+b}$
3. $z=re^{\theta j}$

Comment: I understand hint 2 and 3, but the first one is not clicking for me

Comment: What I think is throwing me off is that first i in numerator. Otherwise it would be in the form of hint 3...

Comment: @JeremyRowler Ah.  So the idea is to remove the $i$ in the numerator by turning it into it's polar form.  Using hint $3$, you should be able to see that $$|i|=1,\operatorname{arg}(i)=\pi/4$$And don't forget the $\pm2k\pi$ for periodic nature of trig functions.

Comment: @JeremyRowler:  Use the third to write the factor $i$ in polar form.